# Unix Shared libraries and VDSO memory mapping

Tags: linux-kernel, shared-libraries, ram, abi

I wondered if linux shared libraries like the gnu libc is shared between process or every single process the linker `ld.so` map a new region of libc to the application if true is this doesn't eat the ram as the same library will be loaded repeatedly for every process in different regions also the same thing for linux **VDSO** the fast **v_syscall** method.

Or linux kernel already mapped all shared libraries in the ram and just every process that needs the library linkage kernel give it access to the library region and by this no huge ram pages

Answer (score 1):

On Linux libraries are typically compiled as position-independent-code, which means that they can be mapped anywhere in the address space without needing relocation fixups.

Each process that loads the library uses a private mapping of the library's segments, but because relocation fixups are not required the text and read-only data mappings remain clean (unmodified), which means that these mappings are backed by only one set of physical pages no matter how many processes they are mapped in.